# What is the meaning of Sachidanand?

Tags: gods, sanskrit, terminology, prayer, meaning

What is the meaning of Sachidanand? What does the word "Sachidanand mean?

I think the word can be broken into - Sat + Chit + Anand.

Does it have some relation with Brahmha (Sat) , Chit (Vishnu) and Shiva (Anand) ?

The word is frequently used to address god. But what does this word actually mean? I am not able to understand it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct - Sat-chit-ananda or Sat-chit-anantha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51789/what-is-correct-sat-chit-ananda-or-sat-chit-anantha)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Brihad Bhagavatamrita](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihad-bhagavatamrita-commentary/d/doc427399.html):

> य सान्द्र-**सच्-चिद्-आनन्द-**विलासाभ्युदयात्मिका ।
> नित्या सत्याप्य् अनाद्य्-अन्ता यानिर्वच्या स्वरूपतः ॥ १७४ ॥
>
> ya sāndra-**sac-cid-ānanda-**vilāsābhyudayātmikā |
> nityā satyāpy anādy-antā yānirvacyā svarūpataḥ || 174 ||
>
> This śakti of Śrī Bhagavān, which is the concentrated essence of **eternality (sat), cognizance (cit), and pleasure (ānanda),** manifests the glorious opulence of the Lord’s pastimes. She has no beginning and no end, and she is beyond description, being eternal, absolutely real, and unlimited.

Thus, Satcitananda describes the unchanging reality of the universe, which takes knowledge to understand the pleasure of.